# Hide divs onload and make disappear others onclick

Tags: html, css, show-hide, onload

I found how to hide/show a div onclick but by default it's show and I would have them hide and only reveal onclick. 
also I would when one is show it make the others hide.

Here is my code:

```
<img id="img1" 
 onclick="document.getElementById ('txt_1').className = document.getElementById ('txt_1').className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden'"
<i>https://codepen.io/drudrudru/pen/KeJQxY</i>
```

Comment: use the stackoverflow's built-in function to inlcude your code instead of using codepen

Answer (score 0):

First add `hidden` class to both of your paragraph.

```js
function showHide(obj) {
  var txt1 = document.getElementById ('txt_1'),
      txt2 = document.getElementById ('txt_2')
  if (obj.id === 'img1') {
    txt1.classList.toggle('hidden'); //it'll toggle the hidden class
    txt2.classList.add('hidden'); //it'll add the hidden class to the other paragraph, if its not already hidden
  }
  else {
    txt2.classList.toggle('hidden');
    txt1.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {display:none} 

     #txt_1 {color:red;
               position: absolute;
               left:242px;
               width: 26%;
               top:30px;
               z-index: 3;}

#txt_2 {color:green;
               position: absolute;
               left:242px;
               width: 26%;
               top:180px;
               z-index: 3;}
```

```html
   <!--- I would have txt hide onload and appear when the corresponding img is onclick--->

       <p id="txt_1" class="hidden">Born on April 22, 1923, in Nashville, Tennessee, Bettie was the second of Walter Roy Page and Edna Mae Pirtle’s six children. During Bettie’s early years, the Page family traveled around the country ...</p>   


       <p id="txt_2" class="hidden"> I would like to appear on click of "img2" and make "txt_1" disappear (and vice versa)</p>
           
 


           <img id="img1" 
     onclick="showHide(this);"
     
     src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/124/124563.png">     
      <br>

           <img id="img2" 
     onclick="showHide(this);"    
     src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/700175-icon-1-cloud-128.png">
```

Then call a function, here i'm naming it `showHide()`, on the images onclick property. It's a good practice to write javascript code separately. Even better if you avoid onclick entirely in this situation. Use event listener instead. Below I'm showing another approach using event listener.

```js
document.getElementById('img1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  showHide(e.target);
});
document.getElementById('img2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  showHide(e.target);
});


function showHide(obj) {
  var txt1 = document.getElementById ('txt_1'),
      txt2 = document.getElementById ('txt_2')
  if (obj.id === 'img1') {
    txt1.classList.toggle('hidden'); //it'll toggle the hidden class
    txt2.classList.add('hidden'); //it'll add the hidden class to the other paragraph, if its not already hidden
  }
  else {
    txt2.classList.toggle('hidden');
    txt1.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {display:none} 

     #txt_1 {color:red;
               position: absolute;
               left:242px;
               width: 26%;
               top:30px;
               z-index: 3;}

#txt_2 {color:green;
               position: absolute;
               left:242px;
               width: 26%;
               top:180px;
               z-index: 3;}
```

```html
   <!--- I would have txt hide onload and appear when the corresponding img is onclick--->

       <p id="txt_1" class="hidden">Born on April 22, 1923, in Nashville, Tennessee, Bettie was the second of Walter Roy Page and Edna Mae Pirtle’s six children. During Bettie’s early years, the Page family traveled around the country ...</p>   


       <p id="txt_2" class="hidden"> I would like to appear on click of "img2" and make "txt_1" disappear (and vice versa)</p>
           
 


           <img id="img1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/124/124563.png">     
      <br>

           <img id="img2" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/700175-icon-1-cloud-128.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the second text to hide as a default, you add the class `hidden` to your html. Your JS will remove it when you toggle. Without changing your structure much, here's a sample that will hide the other block of text when you unhide the other one. It will not unhide it when you hide tho.

There's code repetition here which you could improve, but this should get you on track.

```
   <p id="txt_1">Born on April 22, 1923, in Nashville, Tennessee, Bettie was the second of Walter Roy Page and Edna Mae Pirtle’s six children. During Bettie’s early years, the Page family traveled around the country ...</p>   


   <p id="txt_2"> I would like to appear on click of "img2" and make "txt_1" disappear (and vice versa)</p>




       <img id="img1" 
 onclick="document.getElementById ('txt_1').className = document.getElementById ('txt_1').className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden'"

 src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/124/124563.png">     
  <br>

       <img id="img2" 
 onclick="document.getElementById ('txt_2').className = document.getElementById ('txt_2').className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden'"    
 src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/700175-icon-1-cloud-128.png">
```

```js
function image1Toggle() { 
if (document.getElementById("txt_1").className == "hidden") {
  document.getElementById("txt_1").className = ""; //show
  document.getElementById("txt_2").className = "hidden"; //hide
  
} else {
    document.getElementById("txt_1").className = "hidden"; //hide
}
}


function image2Toggle() { 
if (document.getElementById("txt_2").className == "hidden") {
  document.getElementById("txt_2").className = ""; //show
  document.getElementById("txt_1").className = "hidden"; //hide
  
} else {
    document.getElementById("txt_2").className = "hidden"; //hide
}
}
```

```css
.hidden {display:none} 

     #txt_1 {color:red;
               position: absolute;
               left:242px;
               width: 26%;
               top:30px;
               z-index: 3;}

#txt_2 {color:green;
               position: absolute;
               left:242px;
               width: 26%;
               top:180px;
               z-index: 3;}
```

```html
   <!--- I would have txt hide onload and appear when the corresponding img is onclick--->

       <p id="txt_1">Born on April 22, 1923, in Nashville, Tennessee, Bettie was the second of Walter Roy Page and Edna Mae Pirtle’s six children. During Bettie’s early years, the Page family traveled around the country ...</p>   


       <p id="txt_2" class="hidden"> I would like to appear on click of "img2" and make "txt_1" disappear (and vice versa)</p>
           
 


           <img id="img1" 
     onclick="image1Toggle()"
     
     src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/124/124563.png">     
      <br>

           <img id="img2" 
     onclick="image2Toggle()"    
     src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/700175-icon-1-cloud-128.png">
```